# Using ascii Characters by Import

Tags: python, ascii

So I am making a random name generator and I want to import ASCII instead of just writing out all of it. Is there any way I can import it into my code? I have tried doing the code below which doesn't do anything, please help

When I ran it, nothing happened, maybe I'm using it wrong?   I have never tried importing it before

```
"".join(chr(x) for x in range(32,127))
```

`

Comment: This code produces a string but you never store it anywhere. If you run `python` in a shell and type this, you'd get `' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'` as the output. In an application though, the value is simply lost

Comment: BTW Python strings are Unicode. You can use `ord` to get the character code of a character, eg `"".join(chr(x) for x in range(ord(' '),ord('~')+1))` or `"".join(chr(x) for x in range(ord(' '),ord('Ω')+1))` to produce, well, a lot of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module:

```
import string

# You have to store the result in a variable to use it
choices = ''.join([string.ascii_letters, string.digits, string.punctuation, ' '])

print(choices)
# Output
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ '
```

To use it:

```
import random

# Select one character
print(random.choice(choices))
# Output
';'

# Generate string
print(''.join(random.choices(choices, k=16)))
# Output
Phhs5uYa]O^+]kJz
```

For your information, `choices` is equivalent to your code (same characters):

```
>>> set(choices).symmetric_difference("".join(chr(x) for x in range(32,127)))
set()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `string` module in python for getting the list of ASCII letters.

```
from string import ascii_letters

print(ascii_letters)
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

You can also use `ascii_uppercase` or `ascii_lowercase` for fetching each case's letters.

Answer (score -1):

in your code you just have to assign the result to a variable:

```
ascii_characters = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(32,127))
```

Now `ascii_characters` contains

```
 !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```